# how to get meta desciption value in wordpress

Tags: php

I want meta description of currently executing page in the header.php file in wordpress.

Wordpress function "get_post_meta" is not useful for this. It only returns custom meta tags.

can anyone help me out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going out on a limb and assuming that you're generating meta description tags dynamically. If that's the case, this should get you what you need...

```
<?php
    echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'description', true);
?>
```

If, on the other hand, that's not what you're doing... that method will not work.

Comment: @Nilesh maybe your code lacks global $post. Please check whether $post->ID is set propally. echo $post->ID; will help you.

Comment: @lan: $post->ID is coming properly, still it returning nothing. My code uses "all in one SEO pack". Is that creating issues?

Comment: @Nilesh: also read [this post](http://darrenpangan.com/blog/dynamic-meta-description-for-your-wordpress-blog.html). The All-in-One-SEO-Pack plugin shouldn't be an issue.